# Program Requires Optimization for Minimum Cost

Tags: c

**Here is the problem:**

Cost analysis is an important part of engineering. When you are in practice, you may be asked to write programs to determine the minimum cost for a number of different potential circumstances. Your programs can be used as decision making tools for a project.

Consider the building of an airport with the runway being built on landfill. The contractor has two dump trucks, one with a capacity of 8 tons and the other with a capacity of 12 tons. The contractor uses the trucks to haul fill from a remote site to the airport location. The operating cost per trip for the 8 and 12 ton trucks is $14.57 and $16.26, respectively. One truck cannot make more than 60 percent of the total trips.

Write a program that develops the minimum cost for a given number of tons. Prompt the user to enter the total number of tons. Display the number of trips required for each truck and the total cost. Use a modular design for this program.

**Here is my attempt:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    double mass, sixtyPercentMass;
    int eightCount = 0, twelveCount = 0;

    printf("Enter the number of tons: ");
    scanf("%lf", &mass);
    sixtyPercentMass = 0.6 * mass;

    while((twelveCount*12) < sixtyPercentMass) {
        twelveCount++;
    }
    while((eightCount*8) < (mass - sixtyPercentMass)) {
        eightCount++;
    }

    printf("Total trips required: %d\n", (twelveCount+eightCount));
    printf("Number of 12-ton trucks required: %d\n", twelveCount);
    printf("Number of 8-ton trucks required: %d\n", eightCount);
    printf("Total cost: $%lf", (twelveCount*16.26 + eightCount*14.57));
    return 0;
}
```

**Questions:**

1. How would I account for wasting empty space in trucks?
   Currently, if you have 1 left over, it wastes an entire truck. It would actually be cheaper to use a number of trucks that matches the required mass exactly.
2. How would I properly do the 60% threshold for total trips correctly?
   It currently only does 60% of mass.

Pseudocode or a step in the right direction for the logic required would be helpful.

Comment: What is your question for the SO audience?

Comment: closing the question as too localized :-)

Comment: What does that mean, Aniket?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to separate out the problem from the program.  Attempting to solve for both in one step has you discovering what is needed for your problem as you are dealing with what is needed to get your problem running as software.

To optimize the minimum number of trucks, you should come up with a way that assures no unneeded trucks are used.  One way is to try out using the maximum number of smallest trucks, and "reduce" the solution by swapping out smaller trucks with bigger ones.  Another way is to use the largest trucks available and to then check for partially full trucks which could be substituted with smaller trucks.

However you approach the problem, it doesn't require a computer to figure it out.  Once you can solve the problem to some degree without a computer (even if the scheme is only in your head) then you can set down to the task of writing a program that would do the tasks necessary to implement your solution.

Starting out with the writing as the first step is very much like building a house by beginning to cut and hammer wood, and then wondering later how you're going to eat with no external doors, kitchen, power lines in the walls, etc.

Comment: Okay, I've decided to tackle question 2 as it is the bigger problem of the two. The issue is that I don't know how to solve the problem without the use of a computer. Honestly, it seems like a paradox to me. For example: suppose that I want to move 120 tons of mass. But how do I know the number of total trips?  I guess I can divide 120 by 12 to get 10 trips. And 60% of that would be 6 trips. (continued to my next comment)

Comment: But because I need 10 trips of 12-ton trucks, I am exceeding the 60% threshold, and therefore, I need to use 8-ton trucks. As soon as I start using 8-ton trucks, the original total number of trips increases and therefore, I know need to recalculate the 60% threshold which means that I might've been able to use 10 12-ton trucks after-all!

Comment: A percentage is is a percentage of _something_, since you haven't stated it yet, I'm going to assume that you must use no more than 60% 12 ton trucks.  In which case, you either start out with 8 ton trucks, remove a few, and see if that leaves you with more that 60% 12 ton trucks, or you work from the other end, combining 8 ton trucks into 12 ton trucks, and then checking the appropriate answer, or you just use that odd thing called Algebra and solve the problem without a loop to check and modify the possible answer.